# How to integrate java with control M

Tags: java, control-m

I have few control-M job running on server. I can perform basic operations like to start/stop or pause any JOB from control M Interface.But there is not a development environment available for Control-M.
I have another java application from where I want to start/stop/pause and other basic stuffs of Control-M.
Till now I am totally blank.I don't know which JAVA API, I should use. Do i need to have development environement of Control-M also.

Could some one please help me on this regard?

Answer (score 3):

You should use Web service functionality of Control-M.The details Example is given with API. Run the bat file for configuration.Provide your parameters.Run ClientGui.java.
if you have provided your correct parameters than you should be able to connect with control-M.Please make a comment if you are facing any issue..

Comment: Yes the example indeed provided with API.I am also able to run the program by the step by step guide given in the book,but unfortunately it is still not able to run.

Comment: I mean i am able to compile the program and starts its interface but it is giving error.under major 500  minor 5.

Comment: Though this is not a valid answer but this answer was the most appropriate and related to context .So i am offering you my bounty Instead of wasting it..If you have some Time please provide the correct answer so that i could mark it as Answer

Answer (score 1):

Look at Control-M for Web Services, Java and Messaging.  They also just came out with a Automation API but you have to have Version 9 Fix Pack 2

Comment: I have the API emapi provided by BMC.Since jobs are already running and I don't have the permission to create the JOB.though i have credentials to start restart or kill the job. can i Use the API or any other method like webservice to connect with Java.as i don't know published jobs are providing the webservice or Not.
to use API what are the prerequisite from Control M side..